# Getting year old twitter data in json format

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, twitter

I am trying to access tweets relating to glastonbury 2015 (26th of June 2015 till the 28th of June) using a node server. Now I have gone through the search API and use the search function to retrieve data [link to data I want](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23glasto%20OR%20%23glastonbury%20OR%20%23glastonbury2015%20lang%3Aen%20near%3A%22Glastonbury%2C%20England%22%20within%3A15mi%20since%3A2015-06-26%20until%3A2015-06-27&src=typd). Is there a way to grab this data in JSON format so I can retrieve the actual tweet and the time stamp etc? I have previously used [twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) package to work with the streaming api, is there a way to use it to access these tweet?

Here are the parameters that I entered into the search bar on twitter.com

```
#glasto OR #glastonbury OR #glastonbury2015 lang:en near:"Glastonbury, England" within:15mi since:2015-06-26 until:2015-06-27
```

However it seems with search API I have to use geocode instead of near? is that correct?